# Deep Linking with pin screen and firebase push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, deep-linking, android-deep-link

My goal: I want to send push notification to users. When user tap on that notification, user should navigate to a specific fragment named HitoryDetailsFragment.

What I did: I implemented FirebaseInstanceIdService & FirebaseMessagingService and I'm able to catch Firebase message which is sent from a backend server. I implemented the deep link by an "implicit deeplink". I implemented the navigation using nested navigation graphs. History related screens are placed in a separate navigation graph, graph_history.xml.

What is the issue: When the application is open, everything works fine. I tap on the notification -> I get redirected to HistoryDetailFragment, and when I press the back button, it returns me to the HistoryListFragment. But when the app is closed (not in the recent apps tray), instead of HistoryDetailsFragment, the SplashFragment is opened, and after that I get redirected to the HomeFragment (which is correct, because that's how the flow should work). But, how can I redirect the user to the HistoryDetails, when the app is closed? Also, I should show a Pin screen, where the user should input his pin, if he did not before, before showing the HistoryDetailsFragment.

My code is like below.

```
private fun createPendingIntent(history: History?) = NavDeepLinkBuilder(this).run {
    setGraph(R.navigation.graph_main)
    history?.let {
        //todo when the app is not open (not in tray of recent apps), this destination does not work
        //this instead navigates to SplashFragment
        //which is correct, because we have not entered the pin, so we are not entitled to open the history detail screen
        //but how do I handle this case?
        setDestination(if (it.type.isNews) R.id.nav_history_news else R.id.nav_history_detail)
        setArguments(if (it.type.isNews) HistoryNewsFragmentArgs(it.link).toBundle() else HistoryDetailFragmentArgs(it.id).toBundle())
    }
    createPendingIntent()
}
```

The main nav graph:
[image]

History graph:

[image]

Comment: Did you make it work? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Sorry, but no, we decided to drop this feature... But I remember that I made progress. Try to check what do you have in intent after onCreate(). You will probably see some usefull data in there... But sorry I dont remember the exact details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I made it work. It works fine with navigation graphs using deeplinks.